# Sql query to show only most recent message for specific user?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two sql tables one which has users and the other which has messages.
Right now my query is :

```
SELECT users.memberid,users.username,users.profileimage,users.gender,message.messagebody, message.fromid,message.toid,message.messageid 
FROM message,users 
WHERE message.fromid = users.memberid AND message.toid = '$id' AND recieverdeleted='0' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 55
```

Right now what is being returned is all the information for everymessage regardless of formid(sender's id)
The thing is , I want to only display the most recent message for every from id ..Kind of like how Facebook only shows you the most recent message that friend x has sent you, and not all the messages. I will work on showing all messages after the user has clicked on his friend's most recent message.
Thanks

Comment: This almost exact same question gets asked almost every day. Please search before asking!

Comment: [Mysql documentation for SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: Hi I saw many versions of my question being asked, but couldn't apply it to my own query. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Solved my problem with the following query (bit of a hack): SELECT users.memberid,users.username,users.profileimage,users.gender,message.messagebody, message.fromid,message.toid,message.messageid FROM message,users WHERE message.fromid = users.memberid AND 
message.toid = '$id' AND recieverdeleted='0' AND message.messageid IN (SELECT MAX(messageid) FROM message WHERE toid ='$id' GROUP BY fromid) ORDER BY message.datetime DESC LIMIT 55

Answer (score 1):

Well, you tried. That's good.

```
 SELECT u.memberid
      , u.username
      , u.profileimage
      , u.gender
      , m.messagebody
      , m.fromid
      , m.toid
      , m.messageid 
   FROM users u
   JOIN message m
     ON m.fromid = u.memberid
   JOIN (SELECT fromid,toid,MAX(datetime) max_datetime FROM message GROUP BY fromid,toid) n
     ON n.fromid = m.fromid
    AND n.toid = m.toid
    AND n.max_datetime = m.datetime
  WHERE message.toid = $id 
    AND recieverdeleted = 0 
  ORDER 
     BY datetime DESC LIMIT 55;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first `join` the two tables than apply `order by` because at this moment the command is not sure for which table you want to apply the ordering.
Or better you create an intermediate table from the selection of two tables and then apply the ordering.
Something like:

```
SELECT username,messagebody,fromid FROM(
SELECT users.memberid,users.username,users.profileimage,users.gender,message.messagebody, message.fromid,message.toid,message.messageid,message.datetime 
FROM message,users 
WHERE message.fromid = users.memberid AND message.toid = '$id' AND recieverdeleted='0' )INTERMEDIATE_TABLE ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

I might be wrong in syntax as I have done sql codes a long ago but you should try something very similar like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working

```
SELECT m1.* 
  FROM table_name m1 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(senddate) AS senddate, 
                     IF(member_id2 = 3, member_id1, member_id2 ) AS user 
                FROM table_name 
               WHERE (member_id1 = 3 AND delete1=0) OR 
                     (member_id2 = 3 AND delete2=0) 
              GROUP BY user) m2 
         ON m1.senddate = m2.senddate AND 
           (m1.member_id1 = m2.user OR m1.member_id2 = m2.user) 
     WHERE (member_id1 = 3 AND delete1=0) OR 
           (member_id2 = 3 AND delete2=0) 
   ORDER BY m1.senddate DESC
```

Comment: Is this in response to a different question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this::

```
   SELECT users.memberid,users.username,users.profileimage,users.gender,message.messagebody, message.fromid,message.toid,message.messageid 

FROM message inner join users on (message.fromid = users.memberid)
where  message.toid = '$id' AND recieverdeleted='0' 
ORDER BY message_datetime DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this query is still returning all the  messages for the respective users.

Comment: What exactly do you need??
The query will return you the most recent message of the user in the where clause, do u need the list of all the user, along with their lates message?

Comment: Basically if there are a few messages both with the same fromid and toid the query above will return ALL of those messages (as did my query). I just want the most recent message to the toid from the fromid if there are multiple messages from the same to and from ids.

Comment: Thanks,I understand the LIMIT 1, the only problem with that is that the limit 1 will then not allow messages by other fromids to be shown..Tricky problem!!